# How to make multiple fetches simultaneously on tf2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

In tf1, I could define a list of the required fetches and use

```
sess.run(myList, feed_dict)
```

to get all the elements of the list computed simultaneously by tf1 through the graph. How to do it in tf2.0?

Sample code in tf1:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = [None]*5
for i in range(5):
    a[i] = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([3,3]))
fetch_list = [None]*5
for i in range(5):
    fetch_list[i] = tf.add(tf.gather(a, i), tf.ones([3,3]))

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(fetch_list)
```

Didn't check whether the above code runs or not but I hope you get the point of it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

because tf 2.x executes eagerly by default you *could* just do:

```
a = [None]*5
for i in range(5):
    a[i] = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([3,3]))
fetch_list = [None]*5
for i in range(5):
    fetch_list[i] = tf.add(tf.gather(a, i), tf.ones([3,3]))
```

then `fetch_list` is populated as before.

Depending on the complexity of your real word example, you may also consider the use of the `@tf.function` which builds up an execution graph before pushing the data through to aid optimisation analogous to tf1 (this is a massive oversimplification but you get the point).

You might consider simplifying/reworking the code a little to make facilitate this. Probably best to just work with tensors where possible rather than a list of tensors. It's hard to advise exactly how to accomplish this as I don't know what you have simplified for your example.

For example, if we consider your `fetch_list` to be a `(5,3,3)` tensor rather than a list of 5 `(3,3)` tensors then I'm sure you realise that your simplified example code (more or less) boils down to something like this:

```
@tf.function
def get_list(n):
  return tf.random.normal((n,3,3))

fetch_list = get_list(5)
```

Comment: The above code would execute it serially. To which you've suggested @tf.function so that it would run simultaneously. Vectorization of my complete operation which I've replaced by tf.add(tf.gather,..) is very difficult. Sticking to list is much simpler in my case. However, I'm facing something very strange in the solution you provided earlier. My memory usage grows continuously till out of bounds like when we continously added graph elements in tf1.